# How to change content of quoted value in Guile

Tags: scheme, guile

I have an symbol that evaluates to `(quote ("all"))`. I would like to append "tests" to the end of the list, and get `(quote ("all" "tests"))` but I didn't find how to :

```lisp
(define make-flags ''("all"))
(append make-flags '("tests")) ; Resolves to (quote ("all") "tests")
```

I suppose I would have to remove the quote by evaluate the make-flags twice and re-quote it, but I didn't find how to.

Comment: Notice that `''("all")` evaluates to `(quote (quote ("all")))`, not to `(quote ("all"))` because of the double single-quote at the beginning. Is this what you really needed?

Comment: Yes, that's how it is defined. I meant "once evaluated, it resolves to `(quote ("all"))`, but I am new to guile and I might be wrong.

Comment: Notice that `(quote ("all"))` is just `'("all")`, but you're writing `''("all")`. That extra quote makes all the difference! But anyway, I'm not sure what's your use case. My answer solves your original question ;)

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I don't really agree with your comments about quoting and evaluation here. `''("all")` does indeed evaluate to `'("all")`, just as `'x` evaluates to `x` and `'3` evaluates to `3`. We have to quote such values to talk about them, but that doesn't mean that the quote is part of their actual valuess

Comment: @amalloy Scheme evaluates `(quote whatever)` to `whatever`. `'whatever` is short for `(quote whatever)` so `''x` will evaluate `(quote (quote x))` which becomes a stupid list `(quote x)` but that some REPLs might display as `'x`. Make no mistake. the value is a list with two symbols and there isn't anything more special about the symbol `quote` than `x`. As data they are just as uninteresting to the language.

Comment: @Sylwester Yes, you and I agree. But Óscar López's first comment says something different, which is what I am correcting. Perhaps Óscar López meant "expands to" or "is read as" rather than "evaluates to".

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Surely Scheme strips off the outer quote form in evaluation?

Comment: My first comment should be: “expands to”. And Guile in particular strips off the outer single quote when displaying a list, which I think might confuse a new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'd need to remove the quote first. Try this:

```
(define make-flags ''("all"))
`'(,(append (cadr make-flags) '("tests")))
=> ''("all" "tests")
```

It works because `make-flags` is just a list of this form: `(quote (quote ("all")))` and we can navigate it in the usual way with `car` and `cdr`.

Comment: On my interpeter, it shows `("all" "tests")`, while I would like `(quote ("all tests"))`. Is there a way to re-quote it, if possible after the evaluation of the append?

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the way your interpreter shows the result. `("all" "tests")` is just the way Guile displays `(quote ("all" "tests"))`. So the quote _is_ already there, it's just not shown. That would explain everything ;)

Comment: Anyway: if you really, really want that extra quote there, do this (notice the back quote at the beginning!): `'(,(append (cadr make-flags) '("tests")))

Comment: "`("all" "tests")` is just the way Guile displays `(quote ("all" "tests"))`" Yes, but when I type `make-flags`, I get `(quote ("all"))`, so there is a second quote on the original value. But thanks for the last snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The second you evaluate `''("all")` you get the list `(quote ("all"))` and it is not a quoted list at all. This is a list of to elements, the symbol `quote` and the list `("all")`. If you want to add an element to the second element you do it by recreating the outer list and replacing the second with the new list with the added element:

```
(define (add-second-element ele lst)
  `(,(car lst) (,@(cadr lst) ,ele) ,@(cddr lst)))
    
(add-second-element 'goofy '((donald dolly) (mickey) (chip dale)))
; ==> (donald (mickey goofy) (chip dale))

(add-second-element "tests" ''("all"))
; ==> (quote ("all" "tests"))
```

If you're not too familiar with quasiquote it's possible to do it without since quasiquote is just fancy syntax sugar for `cons` and `append`:

```
(define (add-second-element-2 ele lst)
  (cons (car lst) (cons (append (cadr lst) (list ele)) (cddr lst))))

(add-second-element-2 'goofy '((donald dolly) (mickey) (chip dale)))
; ==> (donald (mickey goofy) (chip dale))
```

Of course if the first element is always `quote` and there are only two elements these can easily be simplified in both versions.